# How to access remote MySQL server using Qt5 on Linux?

Tags: c++, database, qt5.5

I need some help in updating remote MySQL database using QT5.I am working on Linux Ubuntu 12.04.I want my app to connect to remote server and write some data to it.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    //use mysql driver
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

    //set hostname
    db.setHostName("localhost");

    //set db name
    db.setDatabaseName("test");

    //set username and password
    db.setUserName("user");
    db.setPassword("pass");

    //open db
    bool ok = db.open();

    qDebug() << "Db is open: " << ok;

    //define a query
    QSqlQuery query;
    //set query
    query.exec("SELECT * FROM `Persons`");

    //get values from query
    while (query.next()) {
            QString LastName = query.value(1).toString();
            QString  FirstName = query.value(2).toString();
            int age = query.value(3).toInt();
            qDebug() << LastName << " " << FirstName << " " << age;
        }

    //close db
    db.close();

  return a.exec();
 }
```

Comment: create a database with name "test" and a table"Persons"             
 CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);